# Parsing text for URLs with trailing commas

Tags: regex, json, url

I'm looking at a JSON feed from Twitter and trying to make URLs clickable using a regular expression.

The problem  is that there are URLs in the text with trailing commas. A comma can legally be part of a URL, but in this case they're just punctuation inserted by the user.

Is there any way around this? Am I missing something?

Comment: Yes, but then you then won't be able to exclude the commas that actually are punctuation. You can have one but not the other. Do a search for "linkify URL". I have a project on Github you may want to take a look: [LinkifyURL](https://github.com/jmrware/LinkifyURL) and here is the [linkify.js test page](http://jmrware.com/articles/2010/linkifyurl/linkify.html)

Comment: Example data? A URL, directly followed by a comma, followed by another URL. http://foo,http://bar -- if you're lucky, there's a space after the comma. View source here to see that StackOverflow's linkifier code can't handle it either.

Answer (score 2):

You are not missing something; there is no fool-proof way of determining the "intended" URL if it is provided as and is surrounded by plaintext.  Your best bet is to make an educated guess.

A common approach is to check if the punctuation mark(s) in question is followed by a whitespace or is the terminator of the string.  If it is, do not interpret it as part of the URL; otherwise, include it.

Keep in mind this problem isn't limited to commas or a single character (consider the ellipsis, `...`).

Answer (score 1):

You could ignore the last character if it is punctuation (so that punctuation in the middle of a url doesn't affect it).

eg. Regex could be something like:

```
`([a-z/A-Z0-9.,]*?)([.,]?)\s`
```

Warning (the first part of the regex doesn't include all url stuff, so you still need to fix that. But essentially, we have `([a-z/A-Z0-9.,]*?)` which matches the main part of the URL. the `*` allows many characters, but we use `?` so that it isn't greedy.

Then we use `([.,]?)` to match a possible trailing punctuation, and `\s` to match a space or whitespace.

The first subexpression is therefore the url, and you can turn it into a link.

---

If you have access to the internet, you could try accessing the resource to see if it returns a 404 to decide whether the trailing punctuation is part of the URL or actual punctuation.

Comment: Good stuff. But what about the case of two URLs with a comma between them and no space after the comma? The second URL is seen as a substring of the first. You'd have to juggle `pos` and determine if some URL-looking strings were inside others.

Comment: well, the concatenation of both urls would be a valid url in itself, so it isn't possible to know FOR SURE. But, after you get a URL, which MIGHT be the concatenation of multiple URLs, the best you can probably do is try to match the regex `,[a-zA-Z]://`, and split on this. This only works if there is a comma, then a protocol to start the next url.

Comment: In any case, this would be starting to get VERY complicated. And you have to stop at some point, especially due to the ambiguity of these possibilities. Probably 99% of URLs are well-formed, and shouldn't present much difficulties (apart from a single trailing comma or fullstop).